# Find sum of textbox kept inside grid

Tags: c#-4.0, gridview, textbox

I have textbox inside gridview. I want to calculate sum of textbox's values. Currently I am using below code which is taking 2sec for just 300 rows. Is there any other ways which takes less time

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdview_newAudit.Rows)
        {

            TextBox txt = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].FindControl("txt_points");
            violationPoints += Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text);
        }
```

Comment: Have you in `Cells[3]` another controls expect `txt_points`? How the data appears in controls?

Comment: txt_points is inside 3rd column in grid. other control do not expect txt_points